# Android getOrientation description does not match output values

Tags: android, android-sensors

Android [getOrientation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation(float[],%20float[])) function says that:

- values at index 0: Azimuth is between pi and -pi
- values at index 1: Pitch is between pi and -pi
- values at index 2: Roll is between -pi/2 and pi/2

However I get different value ranges when testing with an emulator (Nexus 5 API 25)/device(Samsung API 21). I used Logcat to print the values. The pitch values I get are from -pi/2 to pi/2. With the screen pointing to the sky, the value ranges from 0 to -pi/2, with the screen pointing to the ground, it ranges from 0 to pi/2. 
And the roll goes above pi/2.

Why am I getting values different from the documentation?

My code is as following:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mAccelerometerReading,
                0, mAccelerometerReading.length);
    }
    else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
        System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mMagnetometerReading,
                0, mMagnetometerReading.length);
    }

    if (mAccelerometerReading != null && mMagnetometerReading != null) {
        // Update rotation matrix, which is needed to update orientation angles.
        mSensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mRotationMatrix, null,
                mAccelerometerReading, mMagnetometerReading);


        mSensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, mOrientationAngles);

        Log.d("sensor", Float.toString(mOrientationAngles[1]));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Compare with the Real devices only(Preferable) Because Something Emulator gives different values than the Expected
And here I am attaching one reference Please Have a look.

[Reference 1](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-use-android-sensors-to-detect-orientation-changes/)

[Reference 2](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-advanced-course-practicals/unit-1-expand-the-user-experience/lesson-3-sensors/3-2-p-working-with-sensor-based-orientation/3-2-p-working-with-sensor-based-orientation.html)

What you have do is:-

1. Create Demo Application Which will print this pitch And rolls and then Compare it.

Comment: In my question I mentioned that I also tried it on a real device (Samsung API 21) but I still got the same results.